Cannot connect from host to published port of VSCode Dev Containers since Docker 26
Since I upgraded to Docker 26 I've the problem, that I cannot connect from my host machine to published ports of a VSCode Dev Container.
Interestingly when I configure my applications inside the Dev Container to be accessible from network, everything works.

Dev Container publishes port 3030: cannot access from host machine via localhost:3030 nor 127.0.0.1:3030
Dev Container with "forwardPorts": [3030] configured: cannot access from host machine via localhost:3030 nor 127.0.0.1:3030
Dev container publishes port 3030 and application allows network access: can access from host machine via localhost:3030 and 127.0.0.1:3030

I've checked the release logs of Docker 26, but I couldn't spot anything what might cause this behavior. What could cause this issue?

I encountered a similar issue. In my case, I am accessing the Angular development server through port forwarding in the VSCode dev container. It worked before, but at some point, I could no longer access it from the host-side browser. I was able to avoid this problem by adding --host 0.0.0.0 to the ng serve command.
This is my guess: Previously, when accessing through port forwarding, the connection source was recognized as localhost. It seems that this behavior might have changed, causing the issue.
